# MoudleNotFoundError: No module named 'spinup.utils'

Tags: linux, installation

I'm doing installation from spinningup [page](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/user/installation.html).

I wrote

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --hid "[32,32]" --env LunarLander-v2 --exp_name installtest --gamma 0.999
```

but error occured

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spinup.utils'
```

And i tried to install `spinup` and `utils`,

```
pip install spinup

pip install utils
```

and it says,

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

So these are not answer for error.

How can i solve `spinup.utils` error?

[linux terminal error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75SnB.png)

Comment: Have You completed git - cd - pip actions in order to actually install this library?

Comment: yes i did git clone https://github.com/openai/spinningup.git
cd spinningup
pip install -e .

Answer (score 0):

```
install spinningup again

cd spinningup

pip install -e
```